# AWS S3 java SDK: Can't create bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, kotlin, amazon-s3, minio

I'm tring to create a bucket with following code:

S3 backend i'm using is **minio**

```
runCatching {
    bucket = configuration.getString("storage.bucket")
    s3Client = AmazonS3Client.builder()
        .withEndpointConfiguration(AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration("${configuration.getString("storage.endpoint")}:${configuration.getInt("storage.port")}", ""))
        .withCredentials(AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(BasicAWSCredentials(configuration.getString("storage    .credentials.accessKey"), configuration.getString("storage.credentials.accessToken"))))
        .withPayloadSigningEnabled(false)
        .withClientConfiguration(ClientConfiguration().withProtocol(if(configuration.getBoolean("storage.ssl")) { Protocol.HTTPS } else { Protocol.HTTP }))
        .build()
    s3Client.createBucket(CreateBucketRequest(bucket)) // Exception: com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: usercontent.localhost
                                                       // Exception: Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: usercontent.localhost

    }.onFailure {
        it.printStackTrace()
        exitProcess(0)
    }
}
```

Why create a bucket will send a request to usercontent.localhost?
How can i create a bucket?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hello I had exactly the same problem and the solution was really easy.

You can find more details in this Issue: https://github.com/localstack/localstack/issues/43

Here is your coded fixed:

```java
runCatching {
    bucket = configuration.getString("storage.bucket")
    s3Client = AmazonS3Client.builder()
        .withEndpointConfiguration(AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration("${configuration.getString("storage.endpoint")}:${configuration.getInt("storage.port")}", ""))
        .withCredentials(AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(BasicAWSCredentials(configuration.getString("storage    .credentials.accessKey"), configuration.getString("storage.credentials.accessToken"))))
        .withPayloadSigningEnabled(false)
        .withClientConfiguration(ClientConfiguration().withProtocol(if(configuration.getBoolean("storage.ssl")) { Protocol.HTTPS } else { Protocol.HTTP }))
        .withPathStyleAccessEnabled(true) // YOU HAVE TO ADD THIS
        .build()
    s3Client.createBucket(CreateBucketRequest(bucket)) // Exception: com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: usercontent.localhost
                                                       // Exception: Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: usercontent.localhost

    }.onFailure {
        it.printStackTrace()
        exitProcess(0)
    }
}
```

With this option you avoid using the bucket name in the dns (usercontent.localhost) request and instead uses a path style (localhost/usercontent).